# jQuery detect JSON in post response and if/else clause to redirect

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am a total noob to jQuery and Javascript..

need some help. I have an AJAX request hitting a php script. if the data is validated, the php will return some JSON. if there was an error, it returns an html string with the error texts (I can change this if needed to a json response but am happy with it as html for now...)

The problem I am having is how to identify the json response and code the subsequent if else statement in the JS to determine what to do next.

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $.post( window.location, $("#checkoutCustomer").serialize(), function(data) {
        // TODO: get this to respond to json response or html...
        // need something here to detect presence of JSON in the post response  
        $('#checkoutCustomerResults').html(data); // the html response case
        $(".continue_checkout_link").show(); // the json repsonse case
    });
}
```

Ideally in the success scenario (JSON) the response should trigger the page to load a new URL in the browser, how do I do that also?

Comment: what type of `if-else` checking you want?

Comment: if(response = JSON){ $(".continue_checkout_link").show(); } else {$('#checkoutCustomerResults').html(data);} - something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
$.post( window.location, $("#checkoutCustomer").serialize(), function(data) {
    if(typeof data === 'string')
        $('#checkoutCustomerResults').html(data);
    else if(typeof data === 'object')
       $(".continue_checkout_link").show();
    else
        alert('Something else');
});
}
```

Comment: this s looking like what I am after! but its detecting both responses at a string. is the line "else if(typeof data === 'object')
" setup right to detect JSON? maybe there is somthing missing before to treat the repsonse...

Comment: fixed! I needed the add a header to the PHP: header("Content-Type:application/json");

Comment: as this was the exact asnwer to my question, I shall mark this as the answer, but the answers from RuneFS and zi42 were both excelent

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across a similar requirement. My final solution was to make all responses as JSON. All answers have a `status` parameter in common. `status` can take the values `success`, `error`, or `redirect`, and the rest of the properties are set according to the value of `status`. For instance if `status == 'redirect'`, then I can expect to have another parameter called `redirect` that will contain the URL to redirect to. If `status == 'error'` then I can expect a parameter called `errors` (in my case it contains some more JSON with all the error fields, but in your case you can put your HTML in there)

**EDIT** here is some code to clarify:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
  $.post(window.location, $('#checkoutCustomer').serialize(), function(data) {
    if (data.status == 'redirect') {
      window.location = data.redirect;
      return;
    }
    else if (data.status == 'error') {
      // data.errors will contain some HTML you set on the server side
      // display it however you like
    }
    else if (data.status == 'success') {
      // do whatever you want on success
    }
    else {
      // handle unknown status, should never happen
    }
  }, 'json');
}
```

Notice the `'json'` at the end: it's the 4th parameter to `$.post`, and tells jQuery to expect JSON as a response. This way the `data` param in your callback will contain the already-parsed JSON response as a simple object.

Comment: this sounds promising, could you give me a code example based on my code in the question?

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally use jQuery's capabilities to call a specific handler for a specific status code. That of course requires the server to behave nice and actually use status http status codes correctly Ie. not return `200 OK` in case of failure

you'd then do something like this

```
$.ajax({
   url:"enpoint of service",
   dataType: "json",
   statusCode: {
   200: function(data) {
      //handle success
    },
    500: funciton(){
        //handle internal server error
    }
  }
});
```

or you could use the [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) objects done and fail

```
$.ajax({
       url:"enpoint of service",
       dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(data){
       //handle success here
    }).fail(function(){
       //handle error here
    }).always(function(){
       //ecuted regardless of success or failure
    });
```